# Call Zip Task Multiple Times In Gradle

Tags: gradle

I need to update 9 zip files and the code to do it is about 15 lines.
I'd rather not have to repeat the same 15 lines 9 times in the build script with just different variable names.

Is it possible to call a Zip task in a loop from another task?

Using dynamic tasks seems to be one way but it requires me to list the array of tasks twice which I can see causing an error in future when an extra item is added.

```
[war1, war2, war3, war4, war5, war6, war7, war8, war9].each { warName ->
    task "task$warName"(type: Zip) {
        archiveName = "${warName}.war"          
        //etc etc
    }
}
task all(dependsOn: [taskwar1, taskwar2, taskwar3, taskwar4, taskwar5, taskwar6, taskwar7, taskwar8, taskwar9]) {

}
```

Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firs of all your code might be simplified just to:

```
task allWars

(1..9).each { id ->
   task "taskwar${id}"(type: Zip) {
      archiveName = "war${id}.war"
   } 
   allWars.dependsOn "taskwar${id}"
}
```

And a solution with task [rules](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10F07):

```
tasks.addRule('Pattern: taskwar<ID>') { String taskName ->
    if (taskName.startsWith('taskwar')) {
        task(taskName, type: Zip) {
            archiveName = "${taskName - 'task'}.war"
        }
    }
}

task allWars {
   dependsOn << (1..9).collect { "taskwar$it" }
}
```

There are almost no obvious pros and cons - when it comes to functionality. Basically solution without rules is shorter as you can see, so if you represent attitude *less code is better* that's the way to go. However task rules were created in gradle for this kind of situations - where there are lots of *predefined* tasks. First solution is more *groovier* while the second one is more *gradler* ;)

Comment: In reality my names aren't numerical so I still need an array but add the dependsOn in the for each loop is something that I didn't know you could do!

Comment: With groovy & gradle there're really many, many ways to achieve the desired goal.

Comment: This is definitely a cleaner and more concise solution. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks @InvisibleArrow! I've also upvoted your answer, this morning :)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to store the list of 'war' names in a `ext` property and then iterate over it to create the tasks and use a mapping function for defining the dependencies for the `all` task.

```
// Define the variables here
ext.warTaskPrefix = "task"
ext.warNames = ["war1", "war2", "war3", "war4", "war5", "war6", "war7", "war8", "war9"]

// Define the war task dynamically
warNames.each { warName ->
    task "${warTaskPrefix}${warName}"(type: Zip) {
        archiveName = "${warName}.war"          
        //etc etc
    }
}

// Define the task that depends on all war tasks
task all(dependsOn: warNames.collect{ warName -> "${warTaskPrefix}${warName}" }) {

}
```

Comment: Task rules may also be the way to go.

Comment: @Opal can you give an example of using Task Rules as an answer and the pros/cons of it vs this answer.

Comment: Thanks. I realised that I don't need the prefix which simplifies it even more to not need the collect argument. I accepted @Opal answer just because it had two options.